# execute child process in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, child-process

I wanted to know which module should I use to execute a child process from a react application.

The requirement is:
I need to have a button ,on click of which it should run npm test for the application and generate the report which I will render as per my need.
The thing at which i an stuck is to execute that npm test command on click... rest of the part is working fine if I execute the command manually.

I tried using child-process and child-process-promise modules but it does not work.

```js
import { exec } from 'child-process-promise';


testCode = () => {
    exec("cd ../../ && npm test")
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

// it thorws an error in the import 
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined [in index.js of child-proceess-promise module]
```

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbuQD.png)

Comment: What code exactly did you try? What exactly did not work?

Comment: so you have written the script in package.json and you want to run that command from the react ui is thats your question ?

Comment: yes @dileep thats what i need

Comment: @estus updated the code

Comment: It's unclear what child-proce**e**ss-promise really is. If you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise then there's no `split` in index.js.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'execute a child process from a react application'. Are you trying to do this from *client side*? This obviously won't work. From server side it should work. `child-process-promise` is quite popular package that is workable at least.

Comment: added the image for exact error that i am getting in browser

Comment: in package.json of react app.... i have a script "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage --verbose=false --json --outputFile=src/testReport.json" i want to execute this command on click of button

Comment: If you want to offload work from main thread, you can check out service workers instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to execute a shell command / process / program from the web-browser app level.

Only a server-side app can execute a shell command like "npm test", and then pass the results to the front-end app.